# Миграции в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, миграция, migrate

- Можно ли вручную править некорректно составленные миграции в Yii2?

  Например, что делать, если указал неверный тип столбца в миграции, но она уже применена?

  Руками править тип столбца в бд, а затем корректировать миграцию? Или же нужно обязательно откатить миграции, исправить некорректную, и затем опять применить их? Как правильнее?
- Почему в некоторых примерах миграций название создаваемой таблицы указано как `{{%category}}`, а в других примерах как `category`:

```
// Как правильнее?
$this->createTable('{{%category}}', [

// Или так?
$this->createTable('category', [
```

- Почему в миграциях не выносят название таблицы в отдельную переменную?

```
class m150101_185401_create_news_table extends Migration
{
    public function safeUp()
    {
        // Здесь название таблицы
        $this->createTable('news', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'title' => $this->string()->notNull(),
            'content' => $this->text(),
        ]);
        
        // Здесь тоже
        $this->insert('news', [
            'title' => 'test 1',
            'content' => 'content 1',
        ]);
    }

    public function safeDown()
    {
        // И здесь
        $this->delete('news', ['id' => 1]);
        $this->dropTable('news');
    }
}
```

Не правильнее ли сделать так?

```
class m150101_185401_create_news_table extends Migration
{
    // Объявляем перемнную с названием таблицы
    $table_name = 'news';

    public function safeUp()
    {
        // Здесь теперь переменная
        $this->createTable($table_name, [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'title' => $this->string()->notNull(),
            'content' => $this->text(),
        ]);
        
        // Здесь тоже
        $this->insert($table_name, [
            'title' => 'test 1',
            'content' => 'content 1',
        ]);
    }

    public function safeDown()
    {
        // И здесь
        $this->delete($table_name, ['id' => 1]);
        $this->dropTable($table_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> что делать, если указал неверный тип столбца в миграции, но она уже применена?

Зависит от того, где именно применена. Если пока локально или в задаче, которая ещё не влита в ветки разработки - можно откатить всё и переделать. Если же на проде или `dev` ветке для разработки - нужно делать новую миграцию, чтобы не случилось ещё больших непредвиденных обстоятельств и недоразумений среди разработчиков.

Лучше лишняя миграция, чем решение усложнённой ситуации, когда начнутся правки без ведома. Тем более если править вручную потом в БД, отследить кто это сделал не то, чтобы невозможно, но крайне затруднительно. А в случае с миграциями понятно кто что сделал.

> Почему в некоторых примерах миграций название создаваемой таблицы указано как `{{%category}}`, а в других примерах как `category`. Как правильнее?

Правильнее тоже зависит от ситуации. `{{%category}}` указывают тогда, когда у таблиц есть префикс (и указан в настройках) и такая запись автоматически добавит к таблице префикс во время запроса. Без скобочек - будет просто браться наименование таблицы. Так что, если у вас нет префиксов, можно использовать второй вариант (`category`), но только в том, случае, если уверены, что префиксы никогда вам не понадобятся.

> Почему в миграциях не выносят название таблицы в отдельную переменную?

Дело вкуса и удобства. Кто как хочет, тот так и делает. Мы вообще не используем в миграциях эти билдеры, а используем чистые SQL запросы, потому что они нагляднее (особенно если запрос большой). Это к вопросу о вкусе и удобстве